# Skipped pipeline stage in Azure devops

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

## Problem

When the pipeline underneath is triggered, the **Dev** stage is not being run after **Build and push**.

[image]

The pipeline is triggered with a PR with develop as the target branch.

**pipeline.yaml**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - develop

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop

stages:
  # Frontend tests: Triggered by opening new PRs to develop or updating pr to develop.
  - stage: FrontEndTests
    displayName: "Frontend tests"
    condition: eq( variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') #  Trigger stage only for PullRequests
    jobs:
      - template: /templates/pipelines/npm-unit-tests.yml@templates
        parameters:
          triggerType: ${{ variables.triggerType }}

  # Common build triggered by push to master or develop
  - stage: BuildPush
    displayName: "Build and push"
    condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') # Don't perform stage if PR triggered pipeline
    variables:
      envName: "common"

    jobs:
      - template: /templates/pipelines/dockerbuild-dashboard-client.yml@templates
        parameters:
          displayName: "Build docker image"
          deploymentName: "docker_build_push"
          dependsOn: ""

  # Dev deploy stage
  - stage: dev
    displayName: "Dev"
    dependsOn: BuildPush
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    variables:
      envName: "dev"

    jobs:
      - template: /templates/pipelines/webapprelease-dashboard-dev-client.yml@templates
        parameters:
          dependsOn: ""
          deploymentName: "publish_container_to_webapp"
          
  # Test deploy stage
  - stage: test
    displayName: "Test"
    dependsOn: BuildPush
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'))

    jobs:
      - template: /templates/pipelines/webapprelease-dashboard-test-client.yml@templates
        parameters:
          dependsOn: ""
          deploymentName: "publish_container_to_webapp"

  # Prod deploy stage
  - stage: prod
    displayName: "Prod"
    dependsOn: test
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    variables:
      envName: "prod"

    jobs:
      - template: /templates/pipelines/webapprelease-dashboard-prod-client.yml@templates
        parameters:
          dependsOn: ""
          deploymentName: "publish_container_to_webapp"
```

## Question

Why is the Dev stage not run? It seems to me that the conditions for the `dev` stage are **not** met, but I cannot see why.

Comment: the PR is from master to dev?

Comment: PR is from feature branch to dev.

Comment: You have this condition: `    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))` so it will run only the source branch is `master`, not `feature`

Comment: Will it not run for every other Branch than master? Hence the `ne`?

Comment: Oops, my fault, I thought is ‘eq’

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case [`succeded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#succeeded) is evaluated as

> With no arguments, evaluates to True only if all previous jobs in the dependency graph succeeded or partially succeeded.

And `FrontEndTests` was skipped thus while was evaluated as false.

Please change it to

```yaml
  condition: |
    and(
    or
    (
      in(dependencies.FrontEndTests.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped'),
      in(dependencies.BuildPush.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    ),
    ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```

I tested this on this case and it works as above

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  condition: eq( variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Build"
- stage: test
  displayName: Test
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Test"
- stage: test2
  displayName: Test2
  condition: |
    or(
      in(dependencies.build.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped'),
      in(dependencies.test.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    )
  jobs:
  - job: Test2
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Test2"
```

Comment: Will this yield the same result as having `condition: succeeded('previousStage')` ?

Comment: No. If you don't specify dependencied (via `dependsOn`) your stage will be depend on all stages before. `succeeded` gives you false for `skipped`

Comment: But I had `dependsOn: BuildPush` and it was still not working? With condition: succeeded. (from the question)